# Python - Dictionaries displaying values through keys

Tags: python, dictionary, output, display

For the following program:

```
spanishdays = { 'Sunday':'Domingo', 'Monday':'Lunes', \
                'Tuesday':'Martes', 'Wednesday':'Miercoles', \
                'Thursday':'Jueves', 'Friday':'Viernes', \
                'Saturday':'Sabado' }

ui = input("Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'," \
            "'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday': ")

for ui in spanishdays:
    print('The word for ' + ui + ' in Spanish is ' + spanishdays[ui])
```

I thought the output would be: If the user entered Monday, then "`The word for Monday in Spanish is Lunes`"

However, when I run the program I am getting the following output:

```
Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday',
'Saturday': Monday
The word for Sunday in Spanish is Domingo
The word for Monday in Spanish is Lunes
The word for Tuesday in Spanish is Martes
The word for Wednesday in Spanish is Miercoles
The word for Thursday in Spanish is Jueves
The word for Friday in Spanish is Viernes
The word for Saturday in Spanish is Sabado
```

How do I get just:

```
The word for Monday in Spanish is Lunes
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `for` loop

Comment: You are redefining `ui` in the `for` loop, just remove the `for` loop and leave the `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to print out value corresponding to key in dictionary.

Just the use of `spanishdays[ui]` will return value corresponding to key `ui` from `spanishdays` dictionary. Alternatively, you could use `spanishdays.get(ui)` which serves the same purpose but never raises a `KeyError`.

```
spanishdays = { 'Sunday':'Domingo', 'Monday':'Lunes', \
                'Tuesday':'Martes', 'Wednesday':'Miercoles', \
                'Thursday':'Jueves', 'Friday':'Viernes', \
                'Saturday':'Sabado' }

ui = input("Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'," \
            "'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday': ")

print('The word for ' + ui + ' in Spanish is ' + spanishdays[ui])

# Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday': Monday                               
# The word for Monday in Spanish is Lunes
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `for` loop becuase you just want to get one value for `dict`

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: spanishdays = { 'Sunday':'Domingo', 'Monday':'Lunes', \
   ...:                 'Tuesday':'Martes', 'Wednesday':'Miercoles', \
   ...:                 'Thursday':'Jueves', 'Friday':'Viernes', \
   ...:                 'Saturday':'Sabado' }

In [2]: ui = input("Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',""'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday': ")
Enter 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday': Monday

In [3]: print('The word for %s in Spanish is %s '% (ui, spanishdays.get(ui, 'Invalid entry')))
The word for Monday in Spanish is Lunes

In [4]:
```